# GCC strange behavior under bad conversion specification

Tags: c, gcc

This is a simple code to check the behavior of GCC handling conversion specifications.
(i know the warnings and so on, but i just play with the conversions)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i = 15;
  float x = 5.53f;
  printf("i = %d, x = %f\n", i, x);
  
  printf("i = %f, x = %d\n", i, x);
  return 0;

}
```

the output is what make it quite confusing for me because it swaps the two values in printing, the output is :

```
i = 15, x = 5.530000
i = 5.530000, x = 15
```

Can anyone explain this behavior ?

Comment: the same question (wrong format printf) all over again.

Comment: what do you think will happen if you fill petrol car with diesel. 1. Will drive normaly 2. Will not drive 3. Will break. Same is here. You have %d (petrol) and you fill it with diesel (float) or vice versa.

Comment: Good analogy. Although this wasn't the core of my question.

Comment: simply printf expets  (in this ABI) the float value in the sse or math coprocessor register and integer in general uP register. Then when printing the order in function does not matter.  lets see the dissasembly https://godbolt.org/z/dydjye And **YES** success!!!

Comment: is it correct -yes as you put the wrong fuel. It is an UB.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second call to `printf`, the types of the values being passed in don't match the types specified by the format specifiers.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What's *probably* happening in this case is that the ABI passes integer values on the stack and floating point values via floating point registers, so the values just so happen to be in the right place to be printed in a normal-looking way.  But again, because this is undefined behavior you can't depend on this.

Comment: Not on stack but in general purpose registers.